# How to set multiple pidfile in sidekiq.yml file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, queue, task, jobs, sidekiq

From the official wiki page of sidekiq I found:

> https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Advanced-Options

```
---
:concurrency: 5
:pidfile: tmp/pids/sidekiq.pid
staging:
  :concurrency: 10
production:
  :concurrency: 20
:queues:
  - default
  - [myqueue, 2]
```

Now I want to create multiple tasks using the same `sidekiq.yml` file. But use different pid name, such as:

- /tmp/pids/task1.pid
- /tmp/pids/task2.pid

How to write it in the `sidekiq.yml`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do that.  pidfile is designed to be a command line arg only.

Comment: Thank you. Then is it okay: `bundle exec sidekiq -C /config/sidekiq.yml -d task1`, `bundle exec sidekiq -C /config/sidekiq.yml -d task2` ?

Comment: I want to do it as: `bundle exec sidekiq -C /config/sidekiq/task1.yml -d task1`, `bundle exec sidekiq -C /config/sidekiq/task2.yml -d task2`. In this way how the Rails' ActiveJob know which sidekiq task to use?

Comment: bundle exec sidekiq -P pidfile1.pid, bundle exec sidekiq -P pidfile2.pid

Comment: @MikePerham so, putting `:pidfile` in config yml file is meaningless ?